# How to replace quotation marks in front of and at the end of a string with brackets?

Tags: replace, notepad++, brackets, quotation-marks

I'm trying to replace quotation marks with brackets like {}. I need to convert data for a bibtex import, which is not working with the quotation marks. It looks like this:

```
@article{NASIR20159,  
title = "Fault-tolerant context development and requirement validation in ERP systems",  
journal = "Computer Standards & Interfaces",  
volume = "37",  
pages = "9 - 19",  
year = "2015",  
issn = "0920-5489",  
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csi.2014.05.001",  
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0920548914000695",  
author = "S. Zafar Nasir and Tariq Mahmood and M. Shahid Shaikh and Zubair A. Shaikh",  
keywords = "Context development, Requirement validation, Enterprise Resource Planning, Fault tolerance, Data Mining",  
}
```

And the whole file contains about 2000 records like this, plus abstracts which I've removed. I need to replace now all quotation marks in front and at the end of the strings with brackets. In the end it should look like this:

```
@article{NASIR20159,  
title = {Fault-tolerant context development and requirement validation in ERP systems},  
journal = {Computer Standards & Interfaces},  
volume = {37},  
pages = {9 - 19},  
year = {2015},  
issn = {0920-5489},  
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csi.2014.05.001},  
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0920548914000695},  
author = {S. Zafar Nasir and Tariq Mahmood and M. Shahid Shaikh and Zubair A. Shaikh},  
keywords = {Context development, Requirement validation, Enterprise Resource Planning, Fault tolerance, Data Mining},  
}
```

Do you have any idea how I can do this? I've tried notepad++ and multiple replacement expressions but without success.

Comment: https://gerardnico.com/ide/notepad/replace seems to be pretty informative about the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?=\h*\K"(.+)"(?=,)`
- Replace with: `{$1}`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .+?       # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  =         # equal sign
  \h*       # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  "         # double quote
  (.+)      # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
  "         # double quote
  (?=,)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have a comma after
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks Toto. Only one thing is not working. I've mentioned I've excluded the abstract since it is pretty long. But with your solution now every line is getting changed correctly but the abstract line. It looks pretty much the same but is longer and always the last line until one record ends. Could it make a difference that there is no comma behind it like behind all other lines?

Comment: @robinmathar: Just remove the lookahead `(?=,)` from the regex. It should work. Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: It worked perfectly and I could directly import it in my Bibliometrics Analysis. Thanks a lot, made my day!